# Android: QCMediaPlayer could not be located

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have a problem with the mediaplayer since i updatet my android -version to 5.0.2 on my lg-smartphone.

i have a separate class to play the music

```
public class MediaPlayerService {

    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private static SoundPool soundPool;
    public static boolean isplayingAudio = false;
    static int soundID;

    public static enum State {
        Stopped, 
        Playing, 
    }

    static State mState = State.Stopped;

    public static void playAudioFromMediaPlayer(Context c) {

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.hooray);
        if (!mState.equals(State.Stopped)) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mState = State.Playing;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void loadAudioFromSoundPool(Context c, int id) {

        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);   
        soundID = soundPool.load(c, SoundList.soundList.get(id), 1);
    }

    public static void playAudioFromSoundPool() {

        soundPool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    public static boolean isMediaPlayerPlaying() {
        if (mState.equals(State.Playing)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if(mediaPlayer != null || mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {    
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }       

    public void releaseSoundPool() {

    }
 }
```

I want to play a soundfile over the Mainactivity with

```
MediaPlayerService.playAudioFromMediaPlayer(getApplicationContext(), soundID);
```

but i became the following log-message:

```
02-27 12:36:15.829: E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
02-27 12:36:15.829: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
02-27 12:36:15.854: E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
02-27 12:36:15.854: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
02-27 12:36:15.908: E/MediaPlayer(11743): Should have subtitle controller already set
02-27 12:36:15.930: E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
02-27 12:36:15.930: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
02-27 12:36:15.931: E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
02-27 12:36:15.931: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(11743): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
02-27 12:36:15.958: E/MediaPlayer(11743): Should have subtitle controller already set
02-27 12:36:15.962: E/MediaPlayer(11743): Should have subtitle controller already set
02-27 12:36:16.018: E/MediaPlayer(11743): Should have subtitle controller already set
```

With soundpool it works fine, but not with the mediaplayer. What is the reason for that and how can i solve it?

Thanks in advance and sry for my english :)

Comment: Did you ever get any further here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your platform supports the use of QCMediaPlayer I'm afraid - that's why it's giving you all those errors you can find out more by looking at this source:

https://github.com/fallowu/slim_hardware_qcom_media/blob/master/QCMediaPlayer/com/qualcomm/qcmedia/QCMediaPlayer.java

If I were you I'd stick to using soundpool for the time being.

Comment: I got the same error on my Asus device. But what is interesting, I got it in one video, but another one playing correct. Both videos have same audio and video codecs and same bitrate. Could anyone say suggestion what is hapening?

Comment: 2019: I have the same problem as Igor from time to time. Suddenly, a http audio stream could not be played and the error message is: "E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....". Seems like the only helpful action is to do the CLEAR ALL (apps) from the phone menu and restart app. reset MediaPlayer is not helpful. Some serious bug deep inside the native part of Android?

Comment: Possibly, I haven't done Android development since 2015 so I'm probably the wrong person to ask :P

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The fact is that QC mediaplayer sometimes hangs in the native (JNI) module, and there is absolutely no other way to get rid of the problem than to clear app cache. It is completely tragic. See my date.